# Moving SharePoint Pages from one site to another

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We have a client who is not willing to give us access to their SharePoint environment.

The work involves creating a bunch of custom site columns, custom site content types, page layouts and pages from the custom page layouts. We are going to create this in our environment and the plan is to "move" the pages to our client's environment.

The page layouts will also contain few content editor web parts.

I tried downloading the page to the disk and giving it to the client, but the downloaded page does not contain data entered in the content editor web part.

I thought of creating all the custom stuff (columns, content types, page layouts, and pages) in a sub-site and exporting the sub-site and have the client import the sub-site in their environment. At present I am having an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600079/trouble-with-creating-a-custom-page-layout) but is this the correct way of achieving my goal?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the export and import commands (stsadm.exe) for subsite content and it has proved to work in most scenarios.  Just be aware that there are limitations which may or may not apply to your situation, which are described here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/05/27/limitations-of-stsadm-o-export-import-related-to-publishing-sites.aspx.

Is using a third party tool one of your options?  If it is, I would recommend a tool on Codeplex called the Sharepoint Content Deployment Wizard. I have used it to migrate content from one server to another.  One downside to this tool is that it does not use webservice calls so it must be run locally from the Sharepoint server.  I have used it with WSS 3.0, MOSS 2007 and MOSS 2010.

You can find the details here: http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using a custom tool is not an option. We are planning to export and import the site.